# Fatal error: require_once()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm receiving the following error when trying to access my website created through wordpress:

Warning: require_once(/home/wp_s66dqq/keymoneyconcepts.com.au/wp-content/themes/Divi/core/init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/wp_s66dqq/keymoneyconcepts.com.au/wp-content/themes/Divi/functions.php on line 19

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/wp_s66dqq/keymoneyconcepts.com.au/wp-content/themes/Divi/core/init.php' (include_path='.:') in /home/wp_s66dqq/keymoneyconcepts.com.au/wp-content/themes/Divi/functions.php on line 19

Here's an excerpt of functions.php

```
<?php

if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) $content_width = 1080;

function et_setup_theme() {
  global $themename, $shortname, $et_store_options_in_one_row, $default_colorscheme;
  $themename = 'Divi';
  $shortname = 'divi';
  $et_store_options_in_one_row = true;

  $default_colorscheme = "Default";

  $template_directory = get_template_directory();

  $theme_version = et_get_theme_version();

  define( 'ET_CORE_VERSION', $theme_version );

  require_once( $template_directory . '/core/init.php' );

  et_core_setup( get_template_directory_uri() );

  require_once( $template_directory . '/epanel/custom_functions.php' );

  require_once( $template_directory . '/includes/functions/choices.php' );
```

And I can see init.php in the specified path it's trying to look up. These problems tend to go away when I try to log into the back end of WP - the site becomes accessible. But if I clear browser cache the problem arises again

Anybody got any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check your file permission. Provide server to access your files. what is the file permission? and the ownership of the files

Comment: Everything has been opened up permissions wise - i'm still receiving the error.